# CSS not applying on SVG element under font awesome icon

Tags: css, svg, sass, angular7

I have a font awesome icon like this on my page

```
<fa-icon class="file-excel-icon" title="Export to Excel" [icon]="['sil', 'file-excel']"></fa-icon>
```

which translates to this html

[image]

So the class `file-excel-icon` does get added to the element.
I am now trying to modify some css of SVG element but it is never getting applied. I have tried this

```
.file-excel-icon
{
    border:1px solid red;
    svg
    {
        vertical-align: -0.170em !important;
        border:1px solid blue !important;
    }
}
```

and this

```
.file-excel-icon
{
    border:1px solid red;
    .svg-inline--fa
    {
        vertical-align: -0.170em !important;
        border:1px solid blue !important;
    }
}
```

and this

```
.file-excel-icon .svg-inline--fa
{
    vertical-align: -0.170em !important;
    border:1px solid blue !important;
}
```

But nothing seems to work for svg, no style is applying to it, while the style does apply to `fa-icon` element

Comment: If ``document.querySelector("fa-icon").shadowRoot`` returns a value, you are dealing with shadowDOM that prevents your CSS being applied.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - What is the solution in that case?

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet so we can see the problem?

Comment: If it has shadowDOM, contact the ``<fa-icon>``  component author and ask how to style the component. Or ditch it and create your own Icon Component without any dependencies, like I did: https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - The `document.querySelector("fa-icon").shadowRoot` is coming null! So it is not a shadowDOM and so the reason of css being not applied will be something else

Comment: Which library did you use for the ``<fa-icon>`` ?? What is the NPM repo?

Comment: And your first 2 code blocks are not valid CSS...  but I assumed you hand crafted it for this post.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - I am using this `https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome` and actually I found the solution too in there documentation, I just have to add this `transform="down-0.1"` since I want to make the icon go bit down. So it is working now :) Thanks for giving the direction!!